# Get list Friends from SDK Facebook ios

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I'm used sdk facebook to download the list of my friends who use the same application.

Here is the method I use:

```
    -(void)fb_listaAmici
{


    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                 parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name"}
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {


                              NSArray *friendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                              self.listaAmici = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:friendObjects.count];
                              // Create a list of friends' Facebook IDs
                              for (NSDictionary *friendObject in friendObjects) {
                                  [self.listaAmici addObject:[friendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
                              }




                          }];


}
```

for when I go to call the method through a class the result of varibile is null:

```
CoreFoundation = 1141.140000
12/08/2014 18: 02: 14,755 Test2 [2604: 63309] (null)
12/08/2014 18: 02: 15,438 Test2 [2604: 63309] (null)
12/08/2014 18: 02: 15,704 Test2 [2604: 63309] (null)
12/08/2014 18: 02: 15,871 Test2 [2604: 63309] (null)
12/08/2014 18: 02: 16 021 Test2 [2604: 63309] (null)
```

help me please....thank you!

Comment: Have both you and your friends granted user_friends permission to the app?

Comment: Yes of course, if I do NSLog (@ "% @", result);
I press corretamente all friends, but instead when I try to NGLOG outside metedo the variable is empty

Comment: Please note that `/me/friends` returns the user's friends who are also using your app:

_In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's
**friends who are also using your app**. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends._

from [Facebook Platform Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading?locale=en_GB).

Comment: what is result type? isn't it an NSArray?

Comment: result is Nsdisctionary

Answer (score 0):

what is result type? isn't it an NSArray?
Try to do:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends?fields= installed,id..." 
completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
    //(check the results' type!)
        strongSelf.listaAmici = results;
}
```

Comment: Nothing :( I understand the variable sempe NULL

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad news:

> After a person has logged in with v2.0 of Facebook Login, calling
>   /v1.0/me/friends and /v2.0/me/friends will both result in the v2.0
>   behaviour - both calls will return the set of the person's friends who
>   also use the app.

again

> In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's
>   friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included
>   all of a person's friends.

As clearly written in the [Facebook Platform Upgrade Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading?locale=en_GB).

So, in development phase, it is highly probable that list is empty.

Again, note that at the top of the document:

> Prevent Broken Experiences in Your Mobile Apps - We Recommend
>   Upgrading to v2.0+ Before December 25th